# alias/ short form of address of silverlight app on hosting

Tags: silverlight, web-hosting

I host my Silverlight app in commercial hosting, but to get it I must put in address field in browser all physical path to aspx file ;/

> http://netmajor.home.pl/SecretaryAppNav.Web/SecretaryAppNavTestPage.aspx

It is some way to configure application that I can write short address of my page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If netmajor.home.pl is under your control, you could simply move a copy of the SecretaryAppNavTestPage.aspx page to the root of your website and rename it to something simpler.

Then you could access it via http://netmajor.home.pl/SL.aspx or whatever you want to call it.

There is no code behind for that page (or you could use the matching .html test page that you will also find in your project).

If you were to make it your default page (index.aspx or default.aspx) you could just use http://netmajor.home.pl/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I copy aspx like You tell, but it need ClientBin folder with xap file. I copy it at root directory but still my app not invoke ;/