# A shorter URL for lengthy hosted application address?

Tags: silverlight, hosting, hyperlink

In [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558864/alias-short-form-of-address-of-silverlight-app-on-hosting) I asked about how to create short form for my silverlight application I host on line. But this solution don't help me.

The problem is that I have my few project in solution in other folders. And in folder with my aspx file which host SL app I have ClientBin folder  with xap file. And when I copy this aspx file to root directory SL blank page was invoke.

When I copy ClientBin folder to root it's the same :/

Any idea to "hack" file on hosting to invoke my SL application with short link ? (now I my write root page[netmajor.home.pl] folder where I have aspx file [SecretaryNavApp] and aspx file[SecretaryNavApp.aspx] so link is very long :/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a redirect page called sl.html (for example) like this in your root:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://netmajor.home.pl/SecretaryAppNav.Web/SecretaryAppNavTestPage.aspx"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And when you enter `netmajor.home.pl/sl.html` into your web browser you'll be redirected to your aspx test page.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the container page back to the root, try changing the relative URL of the Silverlight object, to point to the sub-folder i.e SecretaryAppNav.Web/ClientBin/SecretaryAppNav.xap

Q. Why is your project deployed to SecretaryAppNav.Web instead of the root? Are you not just FTP'ing it all up to the hosting yourself or are you using FPE (Front Page Extensions) to publish it?